# Setup smart contract to enable bid negotiate without cancelling current listing order

Tags: solidity, nft, 0x

anyone know if there is a way to setup a smart contract to enable negotiating an NFT bid without cancelling and creating a new listing each time?

Example:
I set an NFT for sale for 0.8 ETH, someone bids 0.5 ETH. I want to counter that with 0.7 ETH and so on... right now platforms like OpenSea make you re-list for the new price.

I've look at 0x Protocol but doesn't look like that have this ability built-in either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a 0x order is signed, the price cannot be modified.

You would need to create another order (which is off-chain so should be free!)

You can also reuse the same nonce to ensure the previous orders become invalid once the final order is settled.